# How to update() an image in MediaStore

Tags: android, mediastore

To `query` the MediaStore, I simply create an URI with the proper "base URI" and append the IMAGE_ID (which I have from the corresponding thumbnail). Then, I simply invoke the content resolver to get a cursor:

```
    Long IMAGE_ID = 172712; // let's say we have this IMAGE_ID
    Uri baseUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    baseUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(baseUri, ""+ IMAGE_ID);

    // let's just get this one field, description
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION};

    Cursor c = getContext().getContentResolver().query(baseUri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (!c.moveToFirst()) return -1; 
    String description = c.getString(0);  // and we're done :-)
```

However, what if I want to *set* the `MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION` field? Can I, somehow, invoke the `update` method?

```
    Long IMAGE_ID = 172712; // same image...
    Uri baseUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    baseUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(baseUri, ""+ IMAGE_ID);

    // create an object with the value to set
    ContentValues test_values = new ContentValues();
    test_values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Some image text...");

    // i.e., SQL like: UPDATE MEDIASTORE SET DESCRIPTION = "Some image text..." WHERE IMAGE_ID = 172712;
    String sIMAGE_ID = "" + IMAGE_ID;
    int res = getContext().getContentResolver().update(baseUri, test_values, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "= ?", new String[]{sIMAGE_ID });  // works fine!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code works fine (at least in the emulator, Nexus 7 device)! `update` sets the DESCRIPTION "field".